# difference between systime and YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to find data where the difference between now and given time is **less than** **1 week**.
I am new to Oracle so how to get the difference in between systime and oracle date given as for example `2020-08-21T10:06:24.662+04:00`? I'm on **+4** time zone too if it is matter;

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract your timestamp from `SYSTIMESTAMP` and it will give you an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` result as the difference:

```sql
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP '2020-08-21 10:06:24.662+04:00' AS difference,
       CASE
       WHEN SYSTIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP '2020-08-21 10:06:24.662+04:00'
              >= INTERVAL '7' DAY
       THEN '1 week or more'
       ELSE 'Less than 1 week'
       END AS difference
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> DIFFERENCE                    | DIFFERENCE    
> :---------------------------- | :-------------
> +000000034 02:49:11.267635000 | 1 week or more
> ```

The difference was 34 days, 2 hours, 49 minutes, 11 (and a bit) seconds; which is more than 1 week.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8dcec4dfd0df6dc35e903973052b317a)*

---

## Update

> Actually i wanna use in where statement, but I cant use result of it like 34 4:55:8.970134 < 7. Hope u will get me))) should I subtract?

If you have some test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id          NUMBER(10,0)
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
              CONSTRAINT table_name__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  active_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( active_date )
  VALUES ( TIMESTAMP '2020-08-21 10:06:24.662+04:00' );

-- Insert a value exactly 6 days ago.
INSERT INTO table_name ( active_date )
  VALUES ( SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '6' DAY );
```

Then you can subtract the `ACTIVE_DATE` from `SYSTIMESTAMP` and compare it to an `INTERVAL` in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  SYSTIMESTAMP - active_date < INTERVAL '7' DAY;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ID | ACTIVE_DATE                     
> -: | :-------------------------------
>  2 | 2020-09-18T10:25:39.528048+01:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=64c4506d0b0cf67bffaa31d2db82787c)*

Comment: when I use like this: select (systimestamp  - (to_timestamp_tz(ACTIVE_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM'))) result number of diffence between dates and time, so kinda 34 4:55:8.970134. Actually i wanna use in where statement, but I cant use result of it like 34 4:55:8.970134 < 7. Hope u will get me))) should I subtract

Answer (score 0):

I would do the comparison as:

```
where active_date > systimestamp - interval '7' day
```

This assumes all the dates are in the past.  In addition, this can use an index on `active_date`.